# Authentication on dockerized mongodb

Tags: docker, mongodb

I'm using the official mongodb:2.6 docker image. I'm trying to figure out how to enable straightforward authentication using `user:password` mode.

How do I specify mongo must run under authentication?

How do I create each `user:password`?

Answer (score 1):

The MongoDB manual includes tutorials for [enabling authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/enable-authentication/) and [adding a user to a database](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/add-user-to-database/).

Assuming you are running a standalone image called `mongo`, you can pass the parameter to enable authentication by starting your image with a `docker` command line similar to:

```
 docker run --name mongod -d mongo --auth
```

The rest of the steps for enabling and configuring access control are not specific to Docker. After starting `mongod` with the `--auth` parameter you need to create an admin user and then any additional users required.

It's also worth reviewing the MongoDB [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/administration/security-checklist/) for other security considerations.

Note: MongoDB 2.6 reached [end of life](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-2-6-end-of-life) in October, 2016. I  strongly encourage upgrading to a supported version (eg. latest 3.2.x or 3.4.x) for continued support.

Comment: Thanks Stennie. I've got it. I thought there might be a way in order to set up a dockerized mongodb instance with users. I really might be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run the mongo docker instance on your server

   ```
   docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/dataMongo:/data/db mongo
   ```
2. Open bash on the running docker instance.

   ```
   docker ps
   ```

   > CONTAINER IDIMAGE   COMMAND  CREATED STATUS  PORTS  NAMES
   >
   > b07599e429fb   mongo   "docker-entrypoint..."   35 minutes ago  Up 35 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   musing_stallman

   ```
   docker exec -it b07599e429fb bash
   root@b07599e429fb:/#
   ```
3. Enter the mongo shell by typing mongo.

   ```
   root@b07599e429fb:/# mongo
   ```
4. For this example, I will set up a user named ian and give that user read & write access to the cool_db database.

   ```
   > use cool_db

   > db.createUser({
       user: 'ian',
       pwd: 'secretPassword',
       roles: [{ role: 'readWrite', db:'cool_db'}]
   })
   ```
5. Exit from mongod shell and bash.
6. Now run the mongo docker with auth enabled.

   ```
   docker run -d -p 27017:27017 -v ~/dataMongo:/data/db mongo mongod --auth
   ```
7. I was able to connect to the instance running on a Google Cloud server from my local windows laptop using the below command.

   ```
   mongo <ip>:27017/cool_db -u ian -p secretPassword
   ```
8. You can commit an image of the container instance. This will store all changes made to its file system including the /data/db directory. You can run this image anywhere docker-engine is running.

   ```
   docker commit mongodb mongodb-backup
   ```

   Reference: https://blog.madisonhub.org/setting-up-a-mongodb-server-with-auth-on-docker/

The answer is based on my answer in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46645243/3877642

Comment: Is it incorrect to refer to an already keyed in material, which could be the answer for the seeker's question?

Comment: Shouldn't I refer to the stackoverflow links either?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly